# Quantiles in R Programming Language

Tags: r, dataset

How is a quantile calculated in R language?
I have looked up for a solution but the site said that quantile = p*(n+1) where p is the percentage ani n is the number of rows in a dataset.
I am not getting the right answer.
Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Read help("quantile").There are actually many ways of calculating quantiles and R implements quite a few of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- rnorm(100) # sample data
quantile(x)  # quartiles 
quantile(x, c(0.1, 0.9))  # 10th and 90th centiles
```

There are a number of ways to find out about how to do things in R, for example, introductory books (many of them online, e.g., https://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html) and simple functions such as `apropos` and `RSiteSearch`:

```
apropos("foo") # gives you a list of functions that have "foo" in their name
```

Comment: Can you suggest me what formula is being used so that I can verify my results

Comment: I suggest having a look at `?quantile` or `help(quantile)` as Roland suggested. The computational methods are described there, with references ("`quantile` returns estimates of underlying distribution quantiles based on one or two order statistics from the supplied elements in x at probabilities in probs. One of the nine quantile algorithms discussed in Hyndman and Fan (1996), selected by type, is employed." .... etc) -- type is an extra parameter to `quantile` - you can select between 9 algorithms